# Confused by the Origin of an UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I always had the impression the origin of a View defines its position inside a parent view. But in my application the Origin is 0,0 no matter where I move my view on the Interface.

This is the code I use:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float orginX = rect.origin.x;
    float orginY = rect.origin.y;

    NSLog(@"X-Origin %f.", orginX);
    NSLog(@"Y-Origin %f.", orginY);
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure whether its giving rect of your expected view and not the parent view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rect passed in to drawRect: is the view's bounds, not it's frame, so its origin will be 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the drawRect method is passed the frame relative to the view's origin, i.e. the origin will always be 0,0.  This is because you should draw your view without knowing or caring where it is in relation to its superview.